# Barn Door tracker motor battery selection

Tags: batteries, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I am planning to build hinge based barn door tracker, as in the attached picture
[image: Barn Door Tracker]

Its a simple meachanism for astrophotography aid, camera is mounted on one plate and other plate is connected via hinge in one side and lead screw and a stepper motor on other to rotate the lead screw and move the plates apart from each other at constant speed.

The weight to be moved including camera and plate would be roughly between 2kg to 4kg (depending on what lens i use on camera)

Speed required to move at is 0.25 degree angle shift in 1 minute (between two plates) , yes its very low speed but i need to move it constantly every second in a smaller steps, roughly 0.0041 degree/sec.

I am planning to use NEMA17 stepper motor with 4.4 Kg/cm capacity (see link for details specification)
link [here](https://robu.in/product/nema17-4-4-kg-cm-stepper-motor/).

I found that the required driver/shield would be A4988, see spec [here](https://robu.in/product/a4988-driver-stepper-motor-driver-standard-quality/?gclid=CjwKCAjwmf_4BRABEiwAGhDfSaqyTAHS18_8eP33z2zny-ec520t4RVAfUqeoVSv8kkzbcUXT1cowxoCsHMQAvD_BwE)

The lead screw i am planning to use is [here](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B0832Y8Y6Q/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o07_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

Everything will be controlled by Arduino Uno3

based on this configuration my understanding/guess is that i require 12v Battery which can supply current between 2 to 3Amps. meaning a lead-acid battery, something similar to [this](https://www.dealsplant.com/products/zebronics-smf-vrla-battery-12v-7-2ah-ups-solar-rechargeable-battery?variant=32612552147019&currency=INR&utm_medium=product_sync&utm_source=google&utm_content=sag_organic&utm_campaign=sag_organic&gclid=CjwKCAjwmf_4BRABEiwAGhDfSbAN3_yZHfhCSD8PEdn3_BkDi6UIuvfaTrYUO9tSg4eXwY9LogkyPhoCp7cQAvD_BwE)

My questions are.

1. Can i use smaller battery or supply directly via powerbank to the above mentioned configuration? or what can be changed in the config (motor/driver) to achieve same req with lower size battery (9v) or powerbank (if its at all possible)
2. If my load (weight) is less than 3kg, is it possible that i use different driver module for e.g EasyDriver4  (in case low current is required)? what is here the relation between weight on plate, voltage and current motor requires?
3. Can i use lower capacity motor since my required speed is very very low.
4. suggest alternate config (i am looking for cheap and smaller size alternatives)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"I am planning to use NEMA17 stepper motor with 4.4 Kg/cm capacity"_ - why did you choose this motor?

Comment: i saw on internet that people who build similar things has used similar motor. main motivation is to get small steps in rotation and amount of weight i am planning to carry.